# Отсутсвует папка Databases на устройстве при работе с Room Database

Tags: android, room

Начал изучать Room database, вроде все создал правильно и подключил тоже, но при нажатии на кнопку добавления данных в бд, сами файлы с бд в папке databases(её как таковой нет) на устройстве не появляются. Насколько я понял они должны лежать вот тут:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите новичку разобраться с проблемой.

код ExpanseTable:

```
public ExpanseTable() {
}

public ExpanseTable(int id, String paymentType, long amount, String description, boolean isIncome) {
    this.id = id;
    this.paymentType = paymentType;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.description = description;
    this.isIncome = isIncome;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPaymentType() {
    return paymentType;
}

public void setPaymentType(String paymentType) {
    this.paymentType = paymentType;
}

public long getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(long amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public boolean isIncome() {
    return isIncome;
}

public void setIncome(boolean income) {
    isIncome = income;
}
}

public ExpanseTable() {
}

    public ExpanseTable(int id, String paymentType, long amount, String description, boolean isIncome) {
        this.id = id;
        this.paymentType = paymentType;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
        this.isIncome = isIncome;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPaymentType() {
        return paymentType;
    }

    public void setPaymentType(String paymentType) {
        this.paymentType = paymentType;
    }

    public long getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(long amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isIncome() {
        return isIncome;
    }

    public void setIncome(boolean income) {
        isIncome = income;
    }
}
```

Код ExpenseDAO:

```
public interface ExpenseDao {

    @Insert
    void insertExpense (ExpanseTable expanseTable);

    @Update
    void updateExpense (ExpanseTable expanseTable);

    @Query("delete from expense where id=:id")
    void delete (int id);

    @Query("select * from expense")
    List<ExpanseTable> getAll();

}
```

код ExpenseDatabase:

```
@Database(entities = {ExpanseTable.class}, version = 1)

public abstract class ExpenseDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract ExpenseDao getDao();

    public static volatile ExpenseDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static ExpenseDatabase getInstance(Context context){
        if (INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context, ExpenseDatabase.class, "expense")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

код кнопки на добавление:

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityAddBinding binding;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityAddBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        binding.addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View view) {

                String amount = binding.amount.getText().toString();
                String type = binding.paymentType.getText().toString();
                String desc = binding.description.getText().toString();
                boolean isIncome = binding.incomeRadio.isChecked();

                ExpanseTable expanseTable = new ExpanseTable();

                expanseTable.setAmount(Long.parseLong(amount));
                expanseTable.setDescription(desc);
                expanseTable.setPaymentType(type);
                ExpenseDatabase expenseDatabase = ExpenseDatabase.getInstance(view.getContext());
                ExpenseDao expenseDao = expenseDatabase.getDao();

                expenseDao.insertExpense(expanseTable);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы как-то неудачно вставили сюда код `ExpanseTable` - поправьте. Он помечен аннотацией `@Entity`? Посмотрите в логах - нет ли ошибок.

Comment: Попробуйте отдавать класс чтобы там были все поля заполнены. Для этого можно переопределить пустой конструктор чтобы все хотя бы дефолтными значениями было заполнено Это с котлина конструктор но не пустой. constructor() : this(null, "", "", "")